# Core Data: Folder like functionality

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Im trying to make a entity in core data that acts like a folder, like on a mac basically where you can put a object inside, and another folder. currently i have folders, and the individual bookmark (another entity) and bookmarks can be in the folder, but i cant get Folders to go inside another folder.

Here is my NSFetchedResultsController,

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bookmark" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"Folder"];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folder == %@", self.folder];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Folder"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

if the NSEntityDescription Entity was `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Folder" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];` it would crash with the error,

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath folder not found in entity '.

How can i fix this? i am stumped at this issue.

The Folder entity has a to-many relationship with the bookmark entity, the bookmark entity has the following attributes, title, url. Folder has the following attributes, title, displayOrder, isFolder.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"folder == %@", self.folder];
```

This line is fine when your entity is a bookmark. If you just change the entity to Folder, and leave this predicate in place, then the fetch request will look for the key `folder` on a Folder entity, which doesn't exist according to your data model description above. If you want to fetch all folders, don't set a predicate.

To allow folders to contain folders, you need to define a relationship from the Folder entity to itself, something like this:

[image]

Here the Folder entity has two relationships, a to-many relationship called subfolders, and its inverse, a to-one relationship called parentFolder. The top level folder has `nil` for its parentFolder.

When fetching the folders contained in a folder, you either simply use the set returned by `folder.subfolders`, or a fetch request predicate where `"parentFolder == %@",folder`.

Comment: When I get rid of the predicate I can see the same objects as before, I want it to be like safari bookmarks. So the folder entity pushes another view, which has different bookmarks. This code is from the controller that is pushed once I selected a folder from the main screen.

Comment: Ok, so create another folder entity, or just add a relationship called subfolders, to itself and the other end is subfolders, and do a many-to-one relationship and it should work?

Comment: I deleted all the code last night, but finally just finished re-addding it all. and i still get the same error, `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath folder not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Folder id=2>'`. I added the relationship "folders", the destination is folder, and the inverse is folders. and it has a one-to-many relationship

Comment: Try cleaning the project, also deleting it from the simulator, model changes often don't carry through. If that doesn't work, you need to add a screenshot of your data model to the question.